# Android- how can I convert android.net.Uri object to java.net.URI object?

Tags: android, uri, android-bitmap, fileinputstream

I am trying to get a `FileInputStream` object on an image that the user selects from the picture gallery. This is the android `URI` returned by `android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`

```
content://media/external/images/media/3
```

When I try to construct a java URI object from this object, I get an `IllegalArgumentException` with the exception description **Expected file scheme in URI: content://media/external/images/media/3** whereas the android URI shows the scheme as **content**

**Update**:
Never found a solution for the original question. But if you want the byte stream of an image in the pictures gallery, this piece of code will do that.

```
Bitmap bitmap = Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
ByteArrayInputStream fileInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes.toByteArray());
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You could use the `toString` method of the android `Uri` in combination of the `String` based constructor of the Java `URI`.

```
android.net.Uri auri = new android.net.Uri(what ever);
java.net.URI juri = new java.net.URI(auri.toString());
```

[Android URI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html)   | 
[Java URI](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URI.html)

Comment: Thanks. Tried that. It gives an exception (java.net.URI should have a valid scheme)

Comment: this is wrong and will fail if the URI has characters that need encoding (like space). android.net.Uri.toString() decodes encoded characters, and java.net.URI will throw an exception if you try to construct it on a non-encoded string. the correct solution `huri = new java.net.URI(URLEncoder.encode(auri.toString(), "UTF-8"));`

Comment: @Jeffrey: Uri.toString() returns encoded characters on my Android 4.1.2 device

Comment: @RémyDAVID it does not. i just tried it. for a `a.n.Uri` with a space in it, the space does *not* get encoded. try it yourself: `Uri.parse("content://foo.bar.com/0?file=my goodness").toString()`. you are right that the javadocs state the it returns an encoded string, but it doesn't say what sort of encoding is used.

Answer (score 43):

Found the correct way to open InputStream from content URI:

```
InputStream fileInputStream=yourContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

That's all!

Comment: Thank you!!! so simple, I knew it was there somewhere. The accepted answer might work in some cases, but does not seem to be safe/functional in all cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! Works as a charm when you need to get byte[] from an image picked in the built in gallery!

Comment: This force closes my app and open Binder.class with no source attached. I am sending Contacts.CONTENT_VCF_URI

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution to your original question (convert Uri to URI):

1. Get the real file path (look this code: [Get filename and path from URI from mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/android-get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore))
2. Get the URI using the real path and the constructor: URI(String uri)

If you need more details, look here:

[How to delete a video recorded using an Intent with ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513483/how-deleting-a-video-recorded-using-an-intent-with-action-video-capture)

Answer (score 2):

I voted for jgilrincon's answer. I can't comment due to low reputation, and here goes some additional info - you can use [FileHelper.java](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/FileHelper.java) from Apache Cordova project, it has functions that you need for file handling from Uri strings, considering mediastore as well (and app assets folder)

Particularly this method provides InputStream from Uri:

```
public static InputStream getInputStreamFromUriString(String uriString, Activity cordova)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the String constructing doesn't work have you tried just constructing it your self?

```
android.net.URI auri = new android.net.URI(what ever);
java.net.URI juri = new java.net.URI(auri.getSchema(),
                                     auri.getSchemaSpecificPart(),
                                     auri.getFragment());
```

You might also want to double check that your getting valid data out of Android URI class. The docs as listed in my other answer discuss how it does pretty much no error checking. If there is infact an error the class just spits out garbage anyway and doesn't throw any exceptions. Which could very likely be why the java class which does do validation is throwing an exception.

Comment: Thanks Brian. The uri is returned by android itself. it contains the path of an image in the picture gallery of the phone. so can't do anything about the image. I'll try and post the uri in the questions

Comment: I think you meant getScheme and getSchemeSpecificPart, right?