# Android "Failure delivering result ResultInfo" when Intent is NOT null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-intent, live-wallpaper

I have a custom image preference in my Live Wallpaper that allows a user to choose an image from their SD card to use as a background.  I got the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679330/choosing-background-for-live-wallpaper) and haven't modified it, so it's almost exactly the same except for variable or object names.

I've been getting a few of these stack traces in my dev console:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/com.idunnolol.rageface/rage_fullpanel.png }} to activity {gilleland.software.pixelrain/gilleland.software.pixelrain.PixelRainSettings}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3515)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3557)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2063)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at gilleland.software.pixelrain.PixelRainSettings.getRealPathFromURI(PixelRainSettings.java:107)
at gilleland.software.pixelrain.PixelRainSettings.onActivityResult(PixelRainSettings.java:90)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3890)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3511)
... 11 more
```

I don't get this exception on my own phone.

I've been searching for a while to figure out what's causing the NullPointerException but most of the solutions I have found involve "ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null}".  The stack traces I'm getting actually have Intents with data...so I can't figure out what the NullPointerException is from.

Any and all help is appreciated.  I can provide any necessary code to help solve this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requestCode and resultCode is correct, so I guess the problem is due to one of the variable pointer is not properly initialized in following section of code:

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();   
String RealPath;
SharedPreferences customSharedPreference =        
getSharedPreferences(fingerflashpro.SHARED_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = customSharedPreference.edit ();
RealPath = getRealPathFromURI (selectedImage);
editor.putString("image_custom", RealPath); 
editor.commit();
```

It's probably something related to the selectedImage or RealPath. Comment out most of the codes and debug it line by line.

Comment: The only problem with trying to find the cause of this exception is that I don't get this error on my own phone or any device that my friends own.

Comment: I think the problem is due to getRealPathFromURI. it doesn't have consisten behavior across different devices. For example, some pictures taken from camera need not return a URI everytime

Comment: That's definitely where the exception is occurring, and only on certain phones, but why throw an exception when there is data being returned?

Comment: What do you mean? NullPointerException is thrown out on line 107 so there must be a pointer pointing to nothing. Just check what's on line 107

Comment: Ah, you're right, I need to change my title.  RealPath is returning null ( I'm assuming).  

But there's no fix for this?  All I can do is add a catch but that won't fix the issue of not being able to choose images for some users.

Comment: If getRealPathFromURI is on line 107, all I can suggest is to use another method to read image. Like I said it is not consistent method to invoke on multiple platforms