# Openning Wallpaper application from my button

Tags: android, wallpaper

How can I open the system wallpaper application from my application (in a button click)?
Can I wait for a result, just like we do for browsing images?

Let me be a bit more specific:
My application changes wallpaper depending on battery level. So from more than 75% I use one file, more than 50% show another, and so on...
To do that I allow the user to browse for the image file he/she wants openning  a file browser and select the file. For this there is a button with the text "open browser". I wait for results and get the image.

Now I am trying this:
I want to let the user click on another button with the text "open wallpaper picker" and would like to open that (system default wallpaper picker). Then I will wait for the result, take the new wallpaper and save it to a file for using again when battery gets to that level further times.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [WallpaperManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html) to get the current wallpaper. Not sure how you could prompt for the standard wallpaper picker though.

Another approach is to just use the generic image picker (which is the approach used in [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3707280/663469))