# How can getContentResolver() be called in Android?

Tags: android

I want to know the context in which `getContentResolver()` is called?

I have a scenario like this:
I have an activity A that calls a method `myFunc()` of class B which is not an activity.
So, in class B I have to use `getContentResolver()`. I directly called `getContentResolver()`. It was showing error. Then I called `myFunc(Acitivy act)` from the activity and called  `act.getContentResolver()` which solved my problem. Is this the only way to call `getContentResolver()`, which means it can be used in context with activity or can be used alone.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

`getContentResolver()` is method of class `android.content.Context`, so to call it you definitely need an instance 
of Context ( Activity or Service for example).

Answer (score 56):

You can use like this:

```
getApplicationContext().getContentResolver()
```

with the proper context.

Comment: `getApplicationContext()` is undefined as well when you have to use it in a class which is not Activity.

Comment: Yes in that case you cannot use this way

Comment: From a fragment's context you can use getActivity().getContentResolver()

Comment: use getContext() @PawełGościcki

Comment: @PawełGościcki but mostly will use it from activity class. Hence the high votes on this. But your point is noted. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The `getContentResolver()`method is also used when you query a `Contact`, using a `Cursor` object.  I have used `getContentResolver()` to query the Android phone `Contacts` app, looking for contact info from a person's phone number, to include in my app. The different elements in a query (as shown below) represent what kind of contact details you want, and if they should be ordered, etc. Here is another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587674/android-contacts-display-name-and-phone-numbers-in-single-database-query).

From the [Content Provider Basics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) page from Android docs.

```
// Queries the user dictionary and returns results
mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
    UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI,   // The content URI of the words table
    mProjection,                        // The columns to return for each row
    mSelectionClause                    // Selection criteria
    mSelectionArgs,                     // Selection criteria
    mSortOrder);                        // The sort order for the returned rows
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentResolver;

context = (Context)this;
ContentResolver result = (ContentResolver)context.getContentResolver();
```

Comment: Thank you, don't know why no one said anything about where to import from.

Answer (score 1):

```
  //create activity object to get activity from Activity class for use to content resolver
    private final Activity ActivityObj;

  //create constructor with ActivityObj to get activity from Activity class
    public RecyclerViewAdapterClass(Activity activityObj) {
        this.ActivityObj = activityObj;
    }


     ActivityObj.getContentResolver(),.....,.....,null);
```

Comment: You are answering a 7-year-old question which as a good and accepted answer, as well as a lot of other answers covering more options. Additionally, your answer is just a code snippet with 2 comments. It is generally a good idea to add some explaining text to your code (or even better, write a text answer to which you add code to show, what you are explaining). If you want to answer questions, which is good, try to focus on more recent (preferably unanswered) questions. And if you answer a question which already has answers, try to make sure yours covers points, the other answers do not.

Answer (score 1):

Access contentResolver in Kotlin , inside activities, Object classes &... :

```
Application().contentResolver
```

Comment: I somehow think this is not a good idea. Can say *spider* senses. Thanks for Kotlin anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me
getBaseContext();

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to get the `ContentResolver` from the `context`

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContext().getContentResolver();
```

Link to the documentation : [ContentResolver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver)