# Android contacts Display Name and Phone Number(s) in single database query?

Tags: android, contacts, contactscontract

I'm trying to obtain a list of contacts from the native database with their Display Name and Phone Number (any or all). There are many methods for obtaining this information with several queries to the phone's database, but this introduces considerable overhead.

Here is the query I've been working on, but it results in

```
Uri uri                = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
String[] projection    = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                                        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
String selection       = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = '1'";
String[] selectionArgs = null;
String sortOrder       = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

Cursor people          = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);

int index_id    = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
int indexName   = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
int indexNumber = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

people.moveToFirst();
do {
    String _id    = people.getString(index_id);
    String name   = people.getString(indexName);
    String number = people.getString(indexNumber);
    // Do work...
} while (people.moveToNext());
```

And here's the resulting error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(21549): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column data1
E/AndroidRuntime(21549):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:144)
E/AndroidRuntime(21549):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:114)
E/AndroidRuntime(21549):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.bulkQueryInternal(ContentProviderNative.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime(21549):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:408)
E/AndroidRuntime(21549):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:264)
```

Thoughts? I believe a join may be needed to get all the columns in a single query.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
String[] projection    = new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};

Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

int indexName = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
int indexNumber = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

if(people.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        String name   = people.getString(indexName);
        String number = people.getString(indexNumber);
        // Do work...
    } while (people.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: This code is skipping two contacts saved in the phone.

Comment: I am getting some contacts 2 to 3 times... why so? I want only unique contacts.

Answer (score 14):

The contacts API is extremly tricky and has **several implicit joins**.

Read the [ContactContract](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/provider/ContactsContract.java;h=9138da2f77da5afaffe1f778917bd605adb71d9a;hb=refs/heads/master) and [ContactsProvider2](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/providers/ContactsProvider.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/providers/contacts/ContactsProvider2.java;h=3bee54dc5af753b00197fc8f52a30518f6eb8f29;hb=refs/heads/gingerbread) if you can afford the time.

What do you want? The tables are chained like this:

- Contact 1--* Raw Contact
- Raw Contact 1--* Phone Number (data table)

The API works like this: you select the bottom-most element (a phone number) and implicit join to the topmost element (contact).

You want to use the PHONE URI case (ContactsProvider2 / line 4377). This should select all phone numbers and join up to the contact.

Combine the PHONE uri with some UI magic (for grouping), request the DISPLAY_NAME and the PHONE number (DATA1?) and you should be able to solve the problem.

Comment: these links are taking to same home page, can you pls fix it

Comment: the android git source browser has been offline since the big kernel.org hack last year. You can still fetch the code as described on the android open source page or you can try to google it, e.g. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.0_r1/com/android/providers/contacts/ContactsProvider2.java - I still hope that the git interface will be reinstalled at some point...

Answer (score 1):

Phone numbers are stored in their own table and need to be queried separately. To query the phone number table use the URI stored in the SDK variable ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI. Use a WHERE conditional to get the phone numbers for the specified contact.

```
private String displayName(Uri contactUri) {
        HashSet detail = ContactDetail.getInstance().getContactArray();
        Log.d("ITEM", contactUri.toString());
        String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
        Cursor queryCursor = getActivity().getContentResolver()
                .query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);
        queryCursor.moveToFirst();
        String name = queryCursor.getString(queryCursor.getColumnIndex("display_name"));
        String id = queryCursor.getString(
                queryCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

        if (Integer.parseInt(queryCursor.getString(queryCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
            Cursor pCur = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                    new String[]{id}, null);
            while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                String number = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                Log.d("Contact Name: ", number);
            }
            pCur.close();
        }


        return name;
    }
```

Perform a second query against the Android contacts SQLite database. The phone numbers are queried against the URI stored in ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI. The contact ID is stored in the phone table as ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID and the WHERE clause is used to limit the data returned.