# CustomListView with Checkboxes

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I am a novice with at android programming so please bear with me. I have looked around a lot on StackOverFlow for solution for this but I couldn't understand how it works. So I tried to make one myself. All I want is to be able to view the contacts in a phone in a *listView* with *checkboxes*. This should only happen when a button is clicked. The code is pasted below

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class AddContacts extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

static final String[] FROM = { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };
static final int[] TO = { R.id.contact_name, R.id.phone_number };
ListView list;
Cursor cursor;
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

Button AddNumber;
EditText number1;
EditText number2;
EditText number3;
String contact1;
String contact2;

static final String TAG = "In AddContacts";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondscreen);
    AddNumber = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddNumbers);
    number1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NumberField1);
    number2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NumberField2);
    number3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NumberField3);
    AddNumber.setOnClickListener(this);
    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };
    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP
            + " = '1'";
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
            + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

    cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, selection,
            selectionArgs, sortOrder);

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, FROM, TO);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);


    // Intent intents = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
    // ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    // startActivityForResult(intents, PICK_CONTACT);
    contact1 = number1.getText().toString();
    if (!contact1.matches(regularExpression)) {
        AddNumber.setEnabled(false);
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "onClicked method");
    Intent intent = new Intent(AddContacts.this, TrackLogic.class);
    intent.putExtra("contact1", contact1);

    Log.d(TAG, "contact values are: " + contact1);
    startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

This code is for the individual row in the ListView

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contact_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="John Doe"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/phone_number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/contact_name"
    android:text="(999)999-9999"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="CheckBox" />
```

This code is for the ListView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView style="@style/AppTheme" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This code run without an compilation error but crashes with a null pointer exception.

> 06-22 10:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(18986): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-22 10:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(18986): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   06-22 10:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(18986):   at >com.example.s.AddContacts.onClick(AddContacts.java:68)
>   06-22 10:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(18986):   at >android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
>   06-22 10:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(18986):   at >android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
>   06-22 10:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(18986):   at >android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>   06-22 10:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(18986):   at >android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   06-22 10:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(18986):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   06-22 10:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(18986):   at >android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>   06-22 10:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(18986):   at >java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   06-22 10:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(18986):   at >java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   06-22 10:57:48.177: E/AndroidRuntime(18986):   at >com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong here? It would be great
Thanks.

Comment: Please, write what string is it? AddContacts.java:68

Comment: @Dimmerg - It crashes at it list.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: then either your list or adapter is null.. try checking in debug mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** You are loading other xml file in `setContentView`() so your `Listview` is never initialized that's why you get the `NullPointerException`

other reasons might be
I think you are accessing `android.R.id.list` instead of `your-package-name.R.id.list`.

Try to change your `Listview` ID and see if it works..

hope this helps....

Comment: @Michael.. i tried changing the ID of the ListView but it still throws the same error.I am stumped.

Comment: @user2511882 are you sure you are using the same xml in the `setcontentview()`

Comment: No.. setContentView has an xml which loads some other screen

Comment: how will that work then. I want the listview to be displayed only when the button is clicked. If i replace the name then it wont display the button then

Comment: for that you can use same layout with multiple controls or use a different activity depending upon your need

Comment: Sorry to bother again.. but i cant seem to find a method to display the phone numbers. I can display only the contact name.. any help?

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587674/android-contacts-display-name-and-phone-numbers-in-single-database-query

Answer (score 0):

According to your code and xml, I think, you have adapter or listview is null. Check the following things:

1) You have permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />`

2) Returned cursor is not null in string `cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);`

3) Returned listview is not null in string `list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);`

Comment: i tried using Log.d(TAG,"list"+ list) right after list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list); and it showed the output as list null...

Comment: I tried running the debugger and it said list cannot be resolved to a variable