# How to get the group in which contact belongs to?

Tags: android, contactscontract

[Android contacts Display Name and Phone Number(s) in single database query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587674/android-contacts-display-name-and-phone-numbers-in-single-database-query)

The above link gives the details to get the phone number and name in the contacts database.

I also want the group to which the contact belongs to ? How to get this from contacts uri?

Answer (score -1):

1. you need a rooted phone
2. install the Root Explorer app
3. go to /data/data/android.providers.contacts/databases, and you can see all the data tables there.
4. then it is all about sql

Comment: I am trying, the following, int indexgroup = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP); But it is not working.