# I've checked contacts2.db, but contacts table doesn't have display_name column

Tags: android

I pulled contacts2.db from emulator(API 19) and checked contacts table.
[contacts table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qfx7i.png)

It doesn't have display_name column.

However, after executing the following code,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CONTACT); 

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_DATE) {
    ...

    } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CONTACT && data != null) {
        Uri contactUri = data.getData();

        // Perform your query - the contactUri is like a "where" clause here
        Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contactUri
            , null
            , null
            , null
            , null);

        //cursor null check

        try {
            // Double-check that you actually got results
            if (c.getCount() == 0) {
                return;
            }
            c.moveToFirst();
            String[] names = c.getColumnNames();
        } finally {
            c.close();
        }
    }
}
```

When I checked names, the list of columns is

```
 sort_key
 photo_uri
 send_to_voicemail
 contact_status
 contact_status_label
 pinned
 display_name
 phonebook_label_alt
 phonebook_bucket
 contact_status_res_package
 photo_id
 in_default_directory
 custom_ringtone
 _id
 times_contacted
 phonebook_label
 lookup
 display_name_alt
 phonetic_name
 last_time_contacted
 contact_last_updated_timestamp
 has_phone_number
 in_visible_group
 is_user_profile
 display_name_source
 photo_file_id
 contact_status_ts
 phonebook_bucket_alt
 sort_key_alt
 contact_presence
 starred
 photo_thumb_uri
 contact_status_icon
 contact_chat_capability
 phonetic_name_style
 name_raw_contact_id
```

It includes display_name column. How is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about [ContactsContract](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html).

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html#ContractClass) about a **Contract** class

> The class establishes a contract between the provider and other applications by ensuring that the provider can be correctly accessed even if there are changes to the actual values of URIs, **column names**, and so forth.

So the `display_name` column is translated to **actual** display_name by the provider and request is made. The cursor is then translated as per definition in `ContactsContract.`

Comment: I know ContactsContract... Did you check the image which I uploaded? You can see it when you click "contacts table" in the first line. I used SQLite tool to read contacts2.db and the tool showed me the column list.

Comment: Do you want to say that there is no such a column which can be mapped to `display_name`?

Comment: yes. I can see columns of Contacts table in "Columns" table in the following site:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html. no display_name!

Comment: display_name is in raw_contacts table.

Comment: What about [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactNameColumns.html)?

Comment: It is duty of content provider to give you all the data in the columns it promises to give. How it does is a matter of implementation. If Contacts Provider promises you to give `display_name` then it is the duty of Contacts Provider to implement the retrieval of `display_name'. Where it stores? How it gets? As I said is a matter of implementation of  Contacts Provider. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6588402/5969624) to know hoe projection is being formed. This projection will be shot from device or internet, only content provider knows.