# Save Image in Gallery

Tags: android, image, save, gallery

This is my code and I want the save image button to simply save the image to the gallery.

```
package com.nk_apps.hip.hop.lyric.wallpapers;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Wallpapers extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
}
    ImageView display;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.wallpapers);

        display = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVDisplay);
        ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage1);
        ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage2);
        ImageView image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage3);
        ImageView image4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage4);
        ImageView image5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage5);
        ImageView image6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage6);
        ImageView image7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage7);
        ImageView image8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage8);
        ImageView image9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage9);
        Button saveImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSaveImage);

        image1.setOnClickListener(this);
        image2.setOnClickListener(this);
        image3.setOnClickListener(this);
        image4.setOnClickListener(this);
        image5.setOnClickListener(this);
        image6.setOnClickListener(this);
        image7.setOnClickListener(this);
        image8.setOnClickListener(this);
        image9.setOnClickListener(this);
        saveImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.IVimage1:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.aotl);
            break;
        case R.id.IVimage2:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball_so_hard);
            break;
        case R.id.IVimage3:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.eye);
            break;
        case R.id.IVimage4:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.faded);
            break;
        case R.id.IVimage5:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.hiii_power);
            break;
        case R.id.IVimage6:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.i_invented_swag);
            break;
        case R.id.IVimage7:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.lifes_a_bitch);
            break;
        case R.id.IVimage8:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.mack_truck);
            break;
        case R.id.IVimage9:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.opposite);
            break;
        case R.id.bSaveImage:

            break;
        }

    } }
```

I want to know what to put under the last case.
And if I shouldn't put it there could I be told how exactly?

Thanks for any help, really struggling with taking everything in.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Saving any image in the Gallery can be done by :

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), yourBitmap, yourTitle , yourDescription);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't know where to put either of these, as I said before I am a real amateur and still going through tutorials.

Comment: This is the code to save any selected image in the gallery. Use this at places where you want to save it.

Comment: "case R.id.bSaveImage:
 InputStream inps= getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.aotl);
 Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inps);
 MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bmp, "Wallpaper1", "Description");
   break;" 

Am I going along the right lines? I presumed I would have to point the image to a directory in the SD Card at one point?

Comment: http://russenreaktor.wordpress.com/2010/02/20/solved-android-save-image-to-media-provider-on-android/

Comment: How do you implement the method getContentResolver ?

Comment: getContentResolver can be called from any Activity Context. You can read more here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getContentResolver(), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567326/how-does-getcontentresolver-work, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750903/how-can-getcontentresolver-be-called-in-android

Comment: in my case this method save nothing... don't know what a problem

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko with dynamic permissions, you would need to get storage permission from the user before you can save. Without the permission, saving would fail. Check your logs for errors/exceptions.

Comment: Eventually, this answer works for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/8722494/5709159

Answer (score 0):

In an onClick Listener, you can use this to save your image to gallery,

```
FrameLayout mainLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);
                    Random fCount = new Random();
                    int roll = fCount.nextInt(600) + 1;
                    File file = new File(Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator
                            + "/your_folder_name/" + String.valueOf(roll) + ".png");

                    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(mainLayout.getWidth(),
                            mainLayout.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
                    mainLayout.draw(c);
                    FileOutputStream fos = null;
                    try {
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        if (fos != null) {
                            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
                            fos.close();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't know where to put either of these, as I said before I am a real amateur and still going through tutorials.