# NullPointerException when trying to initialize Cursor using getContentResolver()

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-cursor

So what I am trying to do is display my database in another activity and add an onItemClickListener. Then I am sending my info by using a URI to another class. I am retrieving the uri in the recipient class and using it to create a Cursor.
When I try to initialize my Cursor using getContentResolver().query(), I am getting a nullpointerexception within my log. The line of code looks like this:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

The uri variable I am using comes from this line of code:

```
Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
```

To make sure that some sort of uri is being returned, I output the uri in my log and got this:
content://com.example.myfirstapp.ContactProvider/CONTACT/(The id of the item selected)

Here is my log:

```
01-06 21:31:43.913: E/AndroidRuntime(619): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-06 21:31:43.913: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at com.example.myfirstapp.ContactActivity.onCreate(ContactActivity.java:22)
```

The code at line 22:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: please check the uri you are getting from getIntent().getData(); some thing is wrong in that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750903/how-can-getcontentresolver-be-called-in-android
Could that be the reason? That the method needs to be called from a context.. or perhaps not if it's called inside an activity?

Comment: well I know that the uri is successfully being transferred from one activity to another, but I am not exactly sure how to format a uri. I've looked at example at many sites and they all seem different.

Comment: @leenephi where and how would I make the instance of the activity or context? I am calling the method within my activity....where else would i call it?

Comment: Did you remember to add the proper permissions and register your `ContentProvider` in your Android Manifest?

Comment: <provider
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.ContactProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.myfirstapp.ContactProvider" >
        </provider>

Comment: This is what I put in my manifest.

Comment: Nevermind; should be good in your activity..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line should looks like this

```
Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

instead  of this

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
```

You have used uri before you have initialized.
and also check for manifest permissions

```
android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
```

Comment: Actually, I should have put the code in order when posting this, but it is already in order like that.

Comment: what data are you passing with intent.?? and which activity you are opening with the intent.please put all your code here.

Comment: list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent contactIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ContactActivity.class);
                Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactProvider.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(id));
                contactIntent.setData(uri);
                startActivity(contactIntent);
            }
        });

Comment: The code I posted originally is how I am retrieving the uri in my other activity.

Comment: so you want to retrieve phone number after it you clicked on contact??

Comment: After I click on the contact (I am using the name), I want to retrieve all the information about that contact. In my database, I have a name and email so far.

Comment: That is why in the getContentResolver().qeury() I passed the second argument as null, so that I can retrieve all the columns in the database

Comment: android.permission.READ_CONTACTS

have you set this permission to your manifest???

Comment: yes I have, but maybe I formatted it wrong. But if I did set my permission right, then my app would let me extend a class using ContentProvider, which it is letting me do that.

Comment: can u possibly give me a link to a website that shows how to properly set permissions in my manifest, I felt like I did it wrong because i never put android.permission.READ_CONTACTS

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_CONTACTS

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

does the job. Do not call your function before `oncreate`.

Comment: Your answer looks like duplicate of other ones.

Comment: @Regent, that's really interesting. still trying to understand what was i thinking. lol.