# My Context gives me a null reference pointer

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to define a Context in my main Activity  and use it in my AsyncTask, but it gives a null reference?
Here I test it in my main Activity and the same error occur in my AsyncTask:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


public  Context mContext;

public Context getContext(Context context) {

    this.mContext = context;
    mContext.getContentResolver();//  null object reference error
    return mContext;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AppCompatActivity` **is a** `Context`

You do not need that field. Just use `MainActivity.this` where you do need a `Context` within that class.

---

Second problem - If `mContext.getContentResolver();` is throwing null pointer, then you just passed a null context into that method...

Essentially, why do you pass a parameter to a get method?

```
public Context getContext(Context context) { <-- null

    this.mContext = context; // <-- null
    mContext.getContentResolver();//  <-- Just used null... exception!
    return mContext; // <-- null, and this is parameter you just provided, anyway...
```

---

Alternatively,

[How can getContentResolver() be called in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750903/how-can-getcontentresolver-be-called-in-android)

Just directly call `getContentResolver()` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem that I see is that there is no existence of the method `getContentResolver()` so in turn it would make the object reference null because there is no such method maybe. If there is a `getContentResolver` method then you should include that in your example :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to set or get the Context? I would have a separate method for getting and another for setting.

```
public void setContext(Context context) {
    Objects.requireNotNull(context);
    this.mContext = context;
    mContext.getContentResolver();// Not sure if this should do anything?
}

public Context getContext() {
    return mContext;
}
```