# How to get recently played video from device in android?

Tags: android, file, video, device

I want to display recently played video in my application.

I have tried to run query on database to search for recently played video

```java
Uri uri1 = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
String[] projection1 = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE, MediaStore.Video.Media.ALBUM };
String selection1 = MediaStore.Video.Media._ID +" like?";
String[] selectionArgs1 = new String[]{"1"};
Cursor cursor1 = ctx.getContentResolver().query(uri1, projection1, selection1, selectionArgs1, MediaStore.Video.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
```

The above query returns nothing.

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750903/how-can-getcontentresolver-be-called-in-android might help..

Comment: It did not help