# Trouble set location to recorded audio

Tags: android, audio, recorder

I have to following code to launch and the audio recorder on Android:

```
final Intent recordSoundIntent = new Intent
("android.provider.MediaStore.RECORD_SOUND");
String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
File.separator + UUID.randomUUID() + ".3gpp";
recordSoundIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new
File(fileName)));
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(recordSoundIntent,
getString(R.string.record_sound_chooser)), INTENT_SOUND_RECORDING);
```

My problem is the following:

My filename (fileName) has no effect, the Uri returned from
data.getData() returns in my last test run: content://media/external/audio/media/41.
However, this file is created on my sdcard: recording34485.3gpp. If it
is not possible to set custom location upon creating sound it is the
location to this file I would like.

Comment: have any suggestions ?? and how about sdk 2.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was working on the same problem. Could not find a way to set location directly but found a work around solution of getting and renaming it.

Getting file name was dealt with [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore), file is then renamed using java.io.File.renameTo(). You'll need android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in your manifest file for the rename to work.

Here is my test code example:

```
public static final int REQUEST_RECORD_SOUND = 7;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent  = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_RECORD_SOUND);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_RECORD_SOUND){
        String sourcePath = getRealPathFromURI(intent.getData());
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String destPath = root.getPath() + File.separator + "newName.txt";
        File sourceF = new File(sourcePath);
        try {
            sourceF.renameTo(new File(destPath));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error:" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * from:
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore
 */
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```