# Android: Creating video thumbnails from Video URI

Tags: android, string, constructor, uri, thumbnails

I'm budiling an application and it lists all the videos i recorded using the recorder in a list. Is it possible for me to create a thumbnail with the help of Uri instead of the string???

my current code goes as below but it no longer works as my input to the constructor is Uri not string.

```
bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(
                    (db_results.get(position)), Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
            imageThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);
```

I'm returned the error

```
The method createVideoThumbnail(String, int) in the type ThumbnailUtils is not applicable for the arguments (Uri, int)
```

Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Comment: no it doesn't work :( .getpath() doesn't retreive the exact location of the video instead it removes the content:// part only.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/android-get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore solved my problem. update your answer I'll mark it as the correct answer :)