# How to get a name of captured image in Android

Tags: android, android-image, android-capture

after capture the image in android how to get a name that save in SD card to programme? or how to **set a name for capturing image to save in SD card**. such as using incremental number. 
pls give me some sample code

Comment: what is the reason for vote down. ? if you vote down this give reasonable fact for it. because I want to  know how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore)

using this method

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```