# How to convert content:// Uri into actual file path?

Tags: android

how can I get the actual file path on the SD card where a content:// uri is pointing for an image?

Comment: This Question has been already  asked.

 


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore

Comment: Checkout this answer for your problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985286/convert-content-uri-to-actual-path-in-android-4-4/43679934#43679934

Answer (score 13):

I've adapted the code which @hooked82 linked to:

```
protected String convertMediaUriToPath(Uri uri) {
    String [] proj={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, proj,  null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String path = cursor.getString(column_index); 
    cursor.close();
    return path;
}
```

Comment: im finding that doing this on a nexus 5's default file picker doesnt work

Comment: Ya im testing this on a Nexus 5 with a content Uri of `content://com.google.android.gallery3d.provider/picasa/item/5688442732610256002` and it doesn't work.

Comment: Yup that code was posted almost 3 years ago. Android has moved on a bit since then.

Comment: hi tiibsco.did you got the solution

Answer (score 0):

Content URIs have syntax content://authority/path/id, read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentUris.html).
Parse id from content URI and query MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI as follows:

```
long id = ContentUris.parseId(Uri.parse(contentUri));
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
            .query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[]{ MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA },
                    MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ?", new String[]{ Long.toString(id) }, 
                    null);
if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
}
cursor.close();
```

Comment: cursor.getCount is 0. Still not able to get path