# How to get the file path from URI?

Tags: android, pdf, uri, filepath

Please find my code below. I need to get the file path of the pdf document, selected by the user from SDcard. The issue is that the URI.getPath() returns:

```
/file:///mnt/sdcard/my%20Report.pdf/my Report.pdf
```

**The correct path is**:

```
/sdcard/my Report.pdf
```

**Please note** that i searched on stackoverflow but found the example of getting the filePath of image or video, **there is no example of how to get the filepath in case of PDF**?

**My code , NOT all the code but only the pdf part**:

```
 public void openPDF(View v)
 {
     Intent intent = new Intent();
     //intent.setType("pdf/*");
     intent.setType("application/pdf");
     intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
     startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Pdf"), SELECT_PDF_DIALOG);
 }
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent result) 
 {
     if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
     {
         if (requestCode == SELECT_PDF_DIALOG) 
         {
             Uri data = result.getData();
             if(data.getLastPathSegment().endsWith("pdf"))
             {
                String pdfPath = data.getPath();
             } 
             else 
             {
                 CommonMethods.ShowMessageBox(CraneTrackActivity.this, "Invalid file type");   
             }               
          }
      }
 }
```

Can some please help me how to get the correct path from URI?

Comment: Here is the correct answer to the question

[have a look][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore

Answer (score 22):

```
File myFile = new File(uri.toString());
myFile.getAbsolutePath()
```

should return u the correct path

**EDIT**

As @Tron suggested the working code is

```
File myFile = new File(uri.getPath());
myFile.getAbsolutePath()
```

Comment: I don't have the FILE here, i need to get it from the Uri.

Comment: Its returning:
/content:/com.quickoffice.mx.samsung/file%3A%2F%2F%2Fmnt%2Fsdcard%2FMy%2520Report.pdf/My%20Report.pdf?MIME-TYPE=application%2Fpdf

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html

Comment: U can see that method in that link. Description says it returns correct path.

Comment: Great thanks for your help but its not working. I tried both the getAbsolutePath() & getPath(), but its not returning the correct path.

You can try it & you will see the results.

Comment: @Seshu Vinay anwser is wrong. File cann't create object, that start with scheme string `file://`. @Yaqub Ahmad devode after uri.getPath string with `URLDecoder.decode`.

Comment: To correct this use: **File myFile = new File(uri.getPath());** - works well for file://...  URIs.

Comment: It needs to be build specific. Kitkat won't return the same as Lollipop. It's a friggin mess.

Comment: Not working. Testing on API 23

Answer (score 5):

Here is the answer to the question
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore)

Actually we have to get it from the sharable ContentProvider of Camera Application.

EDIT . Copying answer that worked for me

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(mContext, contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String result = cursor.getString(column_index);
    cursor.close();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: That's been the only way of getting the "real" file path for my physical device. I do not know why but my device and my emulator works in a different way.

Comment: MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA is deprecated