# AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client - Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-sdcard, documentfile

I want to pick a file from mysdcard (and then I upload to a server).
I try to use Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to select the file using this post:

[How to use the new SD card access API presented for Android 5.0 (Lollipop)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744842/how-to-use-the-new-sd-card-access-api-presented-for-lollipop)

but when I try to select the file, this is the message I receive from Android studio:

1489-1563/system_process W/AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client

I've searched on the web, and it seems like no OnclickListener on the item I clicked (?).

This is the code I use to pick the file:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 42);
```

And how I handle the response:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri treeUri = data.getData();
        DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, treeUri);

        // List all existing files inside picked directory
        for (DocumentFile file : pickedDir.listFiles()) {
            Log.d("PATH FILE", "Found file " + file.getName() + " with size " + file.length());
        }
    }
}
```

Where is my error?
Sorry but I'm newly in android!

Comment: "this is the message I receive from Android studio" -- that warning message does not seem to have anything to do with your code. "it seems like no OnclickListener on the item I clicked" -- you are asking to open a document tree; you will only be able to click on folders, not files.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry, I'm very newly in android. I've resolved using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885204/how-to-get-the-file-path-from-uri to select the file and obtain the path and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore to convert the result in absolute path. Thanks