# Android image selected from gallery Orientation is always 0 : Exif TAG

Tags: android, bitmap, exif

When I pick an image from gallery to set it on my imageview in android application then I see that *it comes inverted by 180 or 270 or 90 degress*.
 So to check/solve this I used `EXIF` orientations, but it always gives me "0".

I am not able to get what is the problem.

code:

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                    absolutePath = selectedImageUri.getPath();

                    exifMedia = new ExifInterface(absolutePath);
                    String exifOrint = exifMedia.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);

                    exifOrientation = Integer.parseInt(exifOrint);

                    System.out.println("Orientation Tag is:"+exifOrientation);

                    /** Convert URI into byte */
                    ContentResolver cr = getBaseContext()
                    .getContentResolver();
                    InputStream inputStream = cr
                    .openInputStream(selectedImageUri);
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

                    rotatedBMP = getResizedBitmapImage(
                            bitmap, 100, 100,exifOrientation);

                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    rotatedBMP.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,
                            stream);
                    byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                    mimProfileImageBrowse.setImageBitmap(rotatedBMP);
```

method:

```
public  Bitmap getResizedBitmapImage(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth, int exifOrientation) {
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        /**
         *  create a matrix for the manipulation
         */

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        /**
         *  resize the bit map
         */


        /*

         1 = Horizontal (normal) 
2 = Mirror horizontal 
3 = Rotate 180 
4 = Mirror vertical 
5 = Mirror horizontal and rotate 270 CW 
6 = Rotate 90 CW 
7 = Mirror horizontal and rotate 90 CW 
8 = Rotate 270 CW

         */


        switch (exifOrientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:

            rotate = 270;

            break;


        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:

            rotate = 180;


            break;

        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:

            rotate = 90;

            break;

        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:

            rotate = 45;

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }


        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        matrix.postRotate(rotate);

        /**
         * recreate the new Bitmap
         */
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
        resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 65, 65, true);

        return resizedBitmap;

    }
```

Please help. Also `matrix.postROTATE` is not rotating the bitmaps. I dont know why.

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After you get Uri of selected Image call the below functions using this methods,
Like this,

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
Bitmap bitmap = scaleImage(this,selectedImageUri);
```

The two functions to include in your activity are,

```
 public static Bitmap scaleImage(Context context, Uri photoUri) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoUri);
        BitmapFactory.Options dbo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        dbo.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, dbo);
        is.close();

        int rotatedWidth, rotatedHeight;
        int orientation = getOrientation(context, photoUri);

        if (orientation == 90 || orientation == 270) {
            rotatedWidth = dbo.outHeight;
            rotatedHeight = dbo.outWidth;
        } else {
            rotatedWidth = dbo.outWidth;
            rotatedHeight = dbo.outHeight;
        }

        Bitmap srcBitmap;
        is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoUri);
        if (rotatedWidth > MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION || rotatedHeight > MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION) {
            float widthRatio = ((float) rotatedWidth) / ((float) MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION);
            float heightRatio = ((float) rotatedHeight) / ((float) MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION);
            float maxRatio = Math.max(widthRatio, heightRatio);

            // Create the bitmap from file
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = (int) maxRatio;
            srcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
        } else {
            srcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        }
        is.close();

        /*
         * if the orientation is not 0 (or -1, which means we don't know), we
         * have to do a rotation.
         */
        if (orientation > 0) {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(orientation);

            srcBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(srcBitmap, 0, 0, srcBitmap.getWidth(),
                    srcBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        }

        String type = context.getContentResolver().getType(photoUri);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        if (type.equals("image/png")) {
            srcBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        } else if (type.equals("image/jpg") || type.equals("image/jpeg")) {
            srcBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        }
        byte[] bMapArray = baos.toByteArray();
        baos.close();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bMapArray, 0, bMapArray.length);
    }

    public static int getOrientation(Context context, Uri photoUri) {
        /* it's on the external media. */
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
                new String[] { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION }, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.getCount() != 1) {
            return -1;
        }

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getInt(0);
    }
```

To get Uri from File use this :

```
public static Uri getImageContentUri(Context context, File imageFile) {
        String filePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID },
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "=? ",
                new String[] { filePath }, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
            Uri baseUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media");
            return Uri.withAppendedPath(baseUri, "" + id);
        } else {
            if (imageFile.exists()) {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, filePath);
                return context.getContentResolver().insert(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Q. Can you plz tell me what is "MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION"? – Dhrupal Mar 13 '13 
A. its based on your imageview size or the image size what you want to show.. whatever it is 60X60 then 60, 100X100 then 100 @Dhrupal

Comment: I have solved the EXIF problem. Can you please check that why bitmap is not rotating. It is executing correctly all the lines LOGICALLY but it is not rotating the bitmap

Comment: Can you plz tell me what is "MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION"?

Comment: its based on your imageview size or the image size what you want to show.. whatever it is 60X60 then 60, 100X100 then 100 @Dhrupal

Comment: unfortunately this won't work on KitKat as it returns a different Uri for Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Comment: There is a leakage in `static int getOrientation`.  The cursor is not properly closed.

Comment: @MKJParekh i need your help..can you check this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28379130/how-to-set-camera-image-orientation

Comment: in ics,jellybean its not working..camera image rotate 90 degree..but with kitkat it works fine..what is issue?

Comment: @Johnson Sorry, I have no idea about that. You can ask it as new question.

Comment: Thanks for the code bro. But i think you should specify what is MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION here.

Comment: If your trying to get orientation from a URI that its not easy or possible to get  a file path from you could open the URI as a stream and then use the support library to get exif data from a stream. I had to do this when I was targeting api 25 and needed support back to api 19. https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/introducing-the-exifinterface-support-library.html

Answer (score 2):

I guess you should not use "`selectedImageUri.getPath()`" to get the path since it does not really return the image file path. Instead you should use `ContentResolver` to query the value of `MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA` which is the actual path of the image.

Actually if you only want to get the orientation, you don't have to get that from the Exif, simply query the value of `MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION` can give you that.

Comment: I have made it right. but one more problem is that my matrix.postRotate is executing but my bitmap is not rotating

Comment: Cool. Just curious, why do you assign the resizedBitmap twice? Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
        resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 65, 65, true);

Answer (score 2):

it has been long time since questioning. but i countered with same problem, and solved this. when you put file path into contructor of exifInterface, use real path, like "/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/blahbalh.jpg", not using something like /content:/media/external/images/media/blah, whiich gives always 0 info.
hope somebody will be helped. regrads.

Oops. below one is same approach. and here is more.
use this.

```
/**
 * @ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore
 * @param contentUri
 * @return
 */
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Comment: @Piotr what is your device?

Comment: LG G2 . It simply returns null

Comment: @mylifeforIU: Thank you, this guided me on the right track. The path is a problem, mostly from KitKat. For solution see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20559175/690777

Answer (score 1):

try below code :-

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filename);  
int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);  
Bitmap bmRotated = rotateBitmap(bitmap, orientation);
```

call below method:-

```
public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int orientation) {

    try{
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                return bitmap;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
                matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
           case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
               matrix.setRotate(90);
               break;
           case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE:
               matrix.setRotate(-90);
               matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
               break;
           case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
               matrix.setRotate(-90);
               break;
           default:
               return bitmap;
        }
        try {
            Bitmap bmRotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            bitmap.recycle();
            return bmRotated;
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use getRealPathFromURI function:

```
public static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri uri,
            String data) {

    String[] largeFileProjection = { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA };

    String largeFileSort = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID + " DESC";
    Cursor myCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            largeFileProjection, null, null, largeFileSort);
    String largeImagePath = "";
    try {
        myCursor.moveToFirst();
        largeImagePath = myCursor
                .getString(myCursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA));
    } finally {
        myCursor.close();
    }

    return largeImagePath;
}
```

Comment: This answer works for me 'documentFilePath=getRealPathFromURI(getApplicationContext(), uri, data.getDataString()); '

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get either the cursor or Exif interface method to work for me. I wasn't able to get reliable rotation numbers for both front and back cameras on Samsung.

For those looking for a solution which works across both front and back cameras for Samsung and other major manufacturers, this answer by nvhausid is awesome:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18915443/6080472

For those who don't want to click through, the relevant magic is to use the CameraInfo rather then relying on EXIF.

```
Bitmap realImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(mCurrentCameraId, info);
Bitmap bitmap = rotate(realImage, info.orientation);
```

Full code in the link.

Comment: This question is about selecting image from gallery not camera.

Answer (score -2):

When image is captured, it stores an exif data as information about rotation type (portrait - landscape). So the only thing you need to check is the exif data:

```
ExifInterface exifData = new ExifInterface(uri);
        int orientation = exifData.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
        Matrix matrix;
        switch (orientation) {
        case 6:
             matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(90);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            break;
        case 3:
             matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(180);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            break;
        case 8:
            matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(270);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            break;
        default:
            break;
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you already checked if you had set Write and Read permissions in your manifest? because if you did not set them you cant access to exif data of your bitmap, i'm talking about android M.
This is the snippet to rotate a bitmap based on its exif dada.

```
public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(String filePath, Bitmap bitmap) {
    ExifInterface exif;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
        Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        if (orientation == 6) {
            matrix.postRotate(90);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        } else if (orientation == 3) {
            matrix.postRotate(180);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        } else if (orientation == 8) {
            matrix.postRotate(270);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        }
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }


}
```