# Android : BitmapFactory.decodeFile return null... (pathName param verified !)

Tags: android

I don't understand and find why my decodeFile method return null ... here my (very simple) code :

```
...
File f = new File(dataString);
photo_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
Log.i("Data... : ", dataString); //show  "/external/images/media/832"
Log.i("arbre.getString File : ", f.getAbsolutePath()); //show  "/external/images/media/832"
if (photo_bitmap == null) Log.i("BITMAP", "BITMAP IS NULL"); //show this if...my Bitmap is null, why ? 
photo_string = BitMapToString(photo_bitmap); //then java.lang.NullPointerException :/
photo_string = photo_string.substring(0, 10);
...
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: How are you aquiring dataString ?

Comment: Did you check f.exists()? Your dataString does not look right, you should probably try /sdcard instead of /external...

Comment: if i can show f.getAbsolutePath, my file is good no ?
Hmmmm, i will try with /sdcard instead of /external

I forget this : dataString come from to an Intent.getData().getPath()

Comment: No, you should try f.exists() or f.isFile()...

Comment: your point ! f.exist() return false ! 
i look why my Intent doesn't return the good path...

Comment: The file may exist, but it may not be able to be decoded as a bitmap. I noticed the filepath is missing an extension, i.e. .bmp/.png/.jpg if you can add the extension of the file to the absolute path, that may help?

Comment: yes =) thx you two ! i find this "magic method" allow get the correct path from an URI Intent here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10564727/2137454

Answer (score 0):

check if you have set this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

in my case this solved the problem