# Get full path to a video file from uri

Tags: android

I am trying to pick a video, selecting and displaying the video works fine, but when I try to get the full path to the video file I get a wrong path.

In the following code fragment I am trying to obtain the full path to the file:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
File file = new File((uri.getPath()));
```

And then when I set the multipart entity filebody I pass it the `file.toString()`.

I am getting the following exception when trying to upload the file.

```
03-28 12:43:27.129: W/System.err(6018): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /content:/media/external/video/media/32398: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
03-28 12:43:27.157: W/System.err(6018):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
03-28 12:43:27.157: W/System.err(6018):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
03-28 12:43:27.157: W/System.err(6018):     at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.writeTo(FileBody.java:92)
03-28 12:43:27.165: W/System.err(6018):     at org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipart.doWriteTo(HttpMultipart.java:206)
03-28 12:43:27.165: W/System.err(6018):     at org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipart.writeTo(HttpMultipart.java:224)
03-28 12:43:27.169: W/System.err(6018):     at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.writeTo(MultipartEntity.java:183)
03-28 12:43:27.169: W/System.err(6018):     at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:97)
03-28 12:43:27.169: W/System.err(6018):     at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:162)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will need to query `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA` column to get real path of File using URI from `MediaStore.Images.Media` ContentProvider.

see following post for getting   [filename and path from uri from mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore)

Comment: @user1940676 : or see dextor answer in same post

Comment: It's MediaStore.Videos I believe

Comment: it is for video , not image

Answer (score 2):

Get file path from URI::

```
   public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
      Cursor cursor = null;
      try { 
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
      } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
          cursor.close();
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the various answers on StackOverflow regarding taking Uris and turning them into File/file paths, and none of them worked. I asked around, and it appears that this behavior is no longer supported. It was suggested that instead if you need access to the video/image: "Just open the URI directly with ContentResolver's openInputStream".