# Android Get Video URI Source

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, media, android-videoview

I'm developing a video player and I would like to know how I get the URI from a video I launch from an intent I have already configured in the manifest.

So far, all I have is this:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    videoURI = data.getDataString();
    vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoURI));          

}
```

This sends me to a launch error so it must be wrong. I've already taken a look at this: [Get filename and path from URI from mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore) but I don't know if it is what I am looking for and I don't understand how to use the answer. If someone could clarify it for me, send me in the direction or help me in any way it would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri vid = data.getData();
videoPath = getRealPathFromURI(vid)
```