# Get Video Uri From Launched Intent

Tags: android, video, android-intent, media, android-videoview

I've got a video player that can be launched via an intent from the usual applications (gallery, file explorer etc.) but I dont know how to use the video Uri launched from the intent. Ive taken a look at this [Get filename and path from URI from mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore?lq=1) but it makes no sense to me

At the moment im hard coding `setVideoUri()` to a video in my phone but I obviously want this to be able to be for any video in the phone, not just one I set.

If someone can help me out I'd appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I dont know how to use the video Uri launched from the intent

Pass `getIntent().getData()` to `setVideoURI()` on the `VideoView`, assuming (based on tags) that you are using a `VideoView`.