# How to get absolute file path for media uri

Tags: android, uri

I have MediaScannerConnectionClient returning me path and uri like below

```
path=/sdcard
uri= content://media/external/images/media/9834
```

How to find absolute path for the uri ? I tried below and failed and line
Log.d(TAG,"after new File");
does not gets executed.

Looks like there is some error in executing line

```
new File(new URI(uri.getPath()))
```

Any help is highly appreciated.
-regards,
Manju

```
File myFile=null;
try {
    myFile=new File(new URI(uri.getPath()));
    Log.d(TAG,"after new File");
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if(myFile!=null && myFile.exists()){
    Log.d(TAG,"file exists");
    Log.d(TAG,"FilePath: "+myFile.getAbsoluteFile());
}else{
    Log.d(TAG,"given file DOESNOT exist");
```

Answer (score 4):

As default, all media content in MediaStore represented by using [MediaColumn](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html), and its  [DATA](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html#DATA) column containing data stream - absolute file path. So, you can get an absolute path of any media stored in MediaStore like this:

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
    Uri.parse"content://media/external/images/media/1"),null,null,null,null);
c.moveToNext();
String path = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA));
c.close();
```

Comment: Hi Chansuk, Thanks for your response but your solution is not working for me. I get a string and a uri in call back after scan completed. I tried using your code to get absolute path but it is failing.                                                                                                                                                                      path: /sdcard/,                                                             uri: content://media/external/images/media/7950

Comment: What's the result or error? In your case I think 'Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri,null,null,nul,null);'is OK, for more detailed information you may refer some similar question - [question #3401579](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore?rq=1)

Comment: Hi Chansuk, Thanks for your response but your solution is not working for me. I get a string and a uri in call back after scan completed. I tried using your code to get absolute path but it is failing. result ==> /sdcard/ whereas my uri.toString() ==> content://media/external/images/media/7950

Comment: Hi Chansuk, i tried another link in your response but no luck, i keep getting result as /sdcard/

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the getRealPathFromURI(uri) method in the answer of [Get filename and path from uri from mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore?rq=1)

to convert my returned camera uri of

content://media/external/images/media/35733

to

/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/1377243365736.jpg

Comment: Hi chughes, i tried same code but always the response is /sdcard/ iam not sure what is the mistake

Comment: hi, Can you post your complete class?