# Video can not be played by videoView Android

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I am developing video player app. I want this app to be appear as option on selecting video from sdcard, album or any folder of the phone . When i select my video player to play video, it takes to app but video is not playing. I have given permission to read and write external storage in manifest.Below is my code :

```
 Intent in =getIntent();
 file_path = in.getData().getPath();
 System.out.println("file path from sdcard:"+file_path);
  videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);

   MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);        
     Uri uri=Uri.parse(file_path);        
     videoView.setVideoURI(uri);        
     videoView.requestFocus();
         videoView.start();
```

ERROR :

```
 10-19 10:39:40.917: I/System.out(20430): file path from sdcard:/external/video/media/24363
 10-19 10:39:40.987: E/MediaPlayer(20430): Uri is  <URL suppressed>
 10-19 10:39:40.997: E/MediaPlayer(20430): error (1, -2147483648)
 10-19 10:39:41.017: E/MediaPlayer(20430): Error (1,-2147483648)
 10-19 10:39:41.017: D/VideoView(20430): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

EDIT: testing phone : Android 4.1 with 32Gb inbuilt memory and does not have Sdcard.

Comment: Quick question, to rule out a common error: Are you experiencing this while your device is connected to your dev machine (e.g. - your laptop)?

Comment: have you tried `videoView.setVideoURI(in.getData());` ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK in.getData() giving this :-> 10-19 11:55:01.387: I/System.out(307): getdata:content://media/external/video/media/24363

Comment: @Brandon when it is connected or not, video is not playing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer for this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore/10564727#10564727)

```
 public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem, went down many different paths to fix it, and what finally ended up working was the following code block:

```
/* inside onCreate */
VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.loginVideoBackground);
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/raw/lights"));
videoView.start();
```

I had previously tried:

- Extending SurfaceView
- using the answer given by @brinda above (which was resulting in a `NullPointerException`)
- and various other permutations of StackOverflow answers

....sometimes simpler is better

Comment: this helps me a lot! thanks :) i removed my `MediaController`. and it no longer crashes.

Answer (score 0):

`/external/video/media/24363` is not correct, please check. local path must be visit..e.g. /sdcard/video/media/..

Comment: i am getting that file path from intent.getPath(). can you tell me how to get the correct path?

Comment: i am getting this from in.getData.getPath(). can you tell me how to get the correct file path?

Comment: You can push video file(foo.mp4) to /sdcard/foo.mp4, and try

Comment: @CrossleSong I am using Sony Xperia with android 4.1.2 which is having 32Gb inbuilt memory and does not have sdcard.So how to get the file name from intent?

Answer (score 0):

```
videoView.setVideoPath("http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/android_book/movie.mp4");        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.start();
```

Comment: i am asking how to play video from sdcard, not from http.

Comment: The videoView.setVideoURI(vidFile);  is depracated method needs to be replaced by the videoView.setVideoPath(path);setVideoPath("/mnt/sdcard/infinnitti.mp4"); using file

Comment: @altaf I am using Sony Xperia with android 4.1.2 which is having 32Gb inbuilt memory and does not have sdcard.So how to get the file name from intent?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I've experienced similar problems in the past and for each account, what I've ultimately found to be the best solution was to extend SurfaceView, directly. There is a surprisingly small amount of code to write and can easily (relatively speaking) be tailored efficiently to your requirements.

Comment: I am using Sony Xperia with android 4.1.2 which is having 32Gb inbuilt memory and does not have sdcard.So how to get the file name from intent?