# Picking an image from the new Photos application

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using the following `Intent` to allow the user to choose a picture

```
Intent pictureIntent = new Intent();
pictureIntent.setType("image/*");
pictureIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
startActivityForResult(pictureIntent, GALLERY_PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

After getting the result, I am using the following approach ([using this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3414749/269106))

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == GALLERY_PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == mActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            Log.d(TAG, "Gallery image path = " + selectedImage.getPath());
            launchUploadImageActivity(getRealPathFromURI(mActivity, selectedImage));
        }
    }
}

private String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

When I use the new Photos application to choose the picture, I can choose a photo that I presume is on google's servers, since it returns a url to a picture, instead of the file path:

Log output:
    Gallery image path = /0/https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/lRkls4SQwi_afJvjO5QChsWqRwTpDjg-....

Is there any way I can force the user to choose pictures that are local on the phone?

Comment: I'm stuck in days with same problem here. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code to chose picture

```
Intent pictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_PICK, Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URL);
startActivityForResult(pictureIntent, REQUEST_CHOOSE_IMAGE);
```

instead of

```
Intent pictureIntent = new Intent();
pictureIntent.setType("image/*");
pictureIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
startActivityForResult(pictureIntent, GALLERY_PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

Comment: Hmmm I'm still being able to pick an image that is on google+

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your intent:

```
pictureIntent.setData(Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```