# Resolving the path while recieving data from an external app

Tags: android, android-intent

i am implementing the functionality to save file in my app which is being sent by some exteral application.

i have provided support for single and mulitple files. Provided handling for all kind of files.

But i am not able to handle the following scenario.

I view a file from an email client -> View it in QuickOffice -> Click on send -> Choose my app->Then click on save in my app.

In that i get the path in following wrapped in the exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/data/data/com.qo.android.sp.oem/files/temp/Error.log: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I have seen this post which is quite useful for handling uri which has content scheme
[Get filename and path from URI from mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore)

Below is my code

```
Uri uri = (Uri) iterator.next();
                            if ("content".equals(uri.getScheme())) {
                                filePath = getFilePathFromContentUri(uri, hostAcitvity.getContentResolver());
                            }
                            else {
                                filePath = uri.getPath();
                            }
                            fileName = uri.getLastPathSegment();
                            fileSize = hostAcitvity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri).available();
```

Code for getFilePathFromContentUri

```
private String getFilePathFromContentUri(Uri selectedVideoUri, ContentResolver contentResolver)
    {
        String filePath;
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaColumns.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(selectedVideoUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        return filePath;
    }
```

Then i wrap the path in a FileInputStream which is throwing the above exception
Not able to resolve the file path properly. Is this the correct way of finding the path ?

cheers,
Saurav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have seen this post which is quite useful for handling uri which has content scheme

That never worked reliably and will work even less reliably in the future.

> Is this the correct way of finding the path ?

No, because there is no requirement that every `Uri` map to a path on a filesystem that you can access.

Use `getInputStream()` on `ContentResolver` to get an `InputStream` on the `Uri`, and consume the data that way.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark...i got your point and it solved my problem

Comment: Just to add..opening of input steam on content resolver does not work when the file comes from apps like file manager and when file is on the sd card