# get actual filename from phonegap API

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I am trying to upload an image from Android based phonegap application to Google drive. I use the following code to get the image URI and use phonegap file transfer plugin to upload to Google. I am looking for how do we get the file name using the phonegap APIs. The filename and path that I get using the code doesn't give me the real file path and name which should be in "image.jpg" format, rather it gives in following format - content://media/external/images/media/47
I have searched and found that there are ways to convert URI to absolute path ([Get filename and path from URI from mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore)) but all are native code. I am using phonegap framework.

```
    uploadFile: function() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(
                uploadPhoto,
                function(message) { console.log("Failed to get pic"+message); },
                {
                    quality         : 50,
                    destinationType : navigator.camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI,
                    sourceType      : navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
                }
                );


            function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
                console.log("File read"+imageURI);


                var options = new FileUploadOptions();

                //options.fileKey="file.png";
                //options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                //options.fileName="googfile.png";
                //options.mimeType="image/png";

                var params = {};
                params.uploadType = "media";
                options.params = params;

                var headers={'Content-Type': 'image/png', 'Authorization': 'Bearer '+localStorage.access_token};
                options.headers = headers;


                var ft = new FileTransfer();
                //console.log("File name ="+options.fileName);
                //console.log("File transfer URI ="+imageURI);
                ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files"), win, fail, options);
            }

            function win(resp) {
                console.log("Code = " + resp.responseCode);
                console.log("Response = " + resp.response);
                console.log("Sent = " + resp.bytesSent);
            }

            function fail(error) {
                alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
                console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
                console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
            }
    }

};
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this I too am looking at this?

Comment: @greaterKing. I found the answer myself and mentioned below. Any comments welcome.

Answer (score 2):

**Add a JS file with following content -**

```
window.getFileFromURI = function(successCallback, errorCallback, uri) {
    cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "ContentName", "getFileName", [uri]);
}
```

**Add a java file (Android source) with following content -**

```
package org.apache.cordova.contentname;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;

    /**
     * This class gets the actual file path and name from native side to JavaScript.
     */
    public class ContentName extends CordovaPlugin {

        @Override
        public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
            if (action.equals("getFileName")) {
                String uri = args.getString(0);
                this.getRealPathFromURI(uri, callbackContext);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void getRealPathFromURI(String uri, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
            if (uri != null && uri.length() > 0) {
                callbackContext.success(this.getFile(uri));
            } else {
                callbackContext.error("Expected one non-empty string argument.");
            }
        }

        private String getFile(String uri) {

             Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(uri);
             String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
             CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(cordova.getActivity(), contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
             Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
             int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
             cursor.moveToFirst();
             String fileName = cursor.getString(column_index);
             Log.d("", "********************************************");
             Log.d("", fileName);
             Log.d("", "********************************************");
             return fileName;
         }


}
```