# How to save image from Intent.EXTRA_STREAM?

Tags: android, android-intent

Trying to figure out how to save an image to a `File` from an `EasyShare Intent`.

For example: going into the Android Gallery > clicking any image > click the share button > click my app > sends image over.

I am able to receive the image and put it into an ImageView, but I don't know how to save the `URI` to a `File` on the `externalFilesDir()`. I basically want to copy the image from the gallery to my apps `externalFilesDir`.

**Code that receives Intent from other App**

```
// Handles image being sent from other application
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if (type.startsWith("image/")) { handleSentImage(intent); }
    }

private void handleSentImage(Intent intent) {
    Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);

    if (imageUri != null) {
        filename = getImageFilename();
        file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);

        takenPicture.setImageURI(imageUri);
        takenPicture.invalidate();
    }
    else { Log.e("RECEIVED IMAGE", "NULL"); }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get filename and path from uri from mediastore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore)

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski this is kind of what I am looking for, but what if they use a custom app like Instagram. Would it be stored in the MediaStore as well?

Comment: Probably you will get the Url in the Uri if it is external resource, or you will get the local uri, for example image from local instagram folder.

Comment: I'm actually trying to just do the first part: "receive the image and put it into an ImageView", how did you do this?