# Getting the ImageView image location

Tags: android, image

I am using the `ImageView` to display a image with a image stored in SD card. Like this-

```
    ImageView grp_icon=(ImageView)gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            String path="/sdcard/Letsmeet/letsmeet_media/group_images/"+gridImage[position];
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
            grp_icon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

And I am trying to get the image location to display the same image in another activity by sending the location in Intent. But it gives a different location Why?

The code where I get the `ImageView` image location is

```
String groupName=((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label)).getText().toString();
                ImageView grp_image=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
                Bitmap b=((BitmapDrawable)grp_image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                Uri image=getImageUri(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), b);
                String path=image.toString();
                Intent toMangeGroup=new Intent(getActivity(),ManageGroup.class);
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("grp_name", groupName);
                bundle.putString("grp_image", path);
                toMangeGroup.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(toMangeGroup);
```

Here I am getting the path as `"content://media/external/images/media/42424"` but the actual path of the image is `"/sdcard/Letsmeet/letsmeet_media/group_images/1395247992445"`

Comment: i am not sure about this but then it could be that since you are getting the drawable from the image that is why it is not returning the sdcard image path, since the sdcard image path gets converted into the bitmap that you are setting

Comment: Have a look at this Nikolay Nikiforchuk answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore . It tells how you can convert to your full path.

Comment: A little modification would be needed. :-)

Comment: @DharanBro i have posted that in the answer. you can accept if you feel that helped thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("this is path where stored.."
                + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Why not using `Log.d()` instead of `sysout`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for getting file path on sdcard:

`String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "Letsmeet/letsmeet_media/group_images/" + gridImage[position]`;

Answer (score 0):

use this code:may help you..

```
Bitmap mybit=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file1.getAbsolutePath());
image.setImageBitmap(mybit);
```

used to store your image in file format and get the image from that path.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [Get filename and path from uri from mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore). The answer provided by Nikolay Nikiforchuk is the way to go. And that does not only work with the `mediafile` but will also work good with all the files stored on `SDCard`

just replace this line

```
int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
```

with this one

```
int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_data");
```

That would work fine.