# Get image path in Android

Tags: android, image, uri, gallery

When i pick some photos from gallery, they have next uri

```
content://com.google.android.apps.photos.content/0/https%3A%2F%2Flh3.googleusercontent.com%2F1cSCAm2mqyFgOUPR8d_8Modz0Cgu6yn1nsznrhfzQTw%3Ds0-d
```

instead of something like

```
content://media/external/images/media/3728
```

and i cant get path to this image. How can i resolve this problem?

My code:

```
case RC_SELECT_PICTURE:
            Uri pickedImage = data.getData();
            // Let's read picked image path using content resolver
            String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(pickedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));
            cursor.close();
            break;
```

I try to get `filePath` using some methods which I found on StackOverflow, but this path is url. I can download my image using it. I need to get local `filePath`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore

Comment: which device you are using?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I am facing the same issue. I need the local path and not the picasa url.

Answer (score 2):

A `Uri` **has never had to map to a `File` path**.

Now, it turns out that `MediaStore` leaked paths, and a few idiots promoted the pattern of using those leaks, leading lots of developers to think that this was reliable behavior. It wasn't. A `ContentProvider` can serve up all sorts of streams, not backed by a file that you have access to, such as having the file be on internal storage.

If you want the content of the image pointed to by this `Uri`, or you want to know its MIME type, use a `ContentResolver`.

Comment: This shed some light on my uri issue as well, but this would be awesome if you could post or link to some sample code

Comment: @kabuto178: I am not quite certain what sample code you would need. `ContentResolver` has methods like [`openInputStream()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openInputStream(android.net.Uri)) and [`getType()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#getType(android.net.Uri)) that you can use. You can get a `ContentResolver` by calling `getContentResolver()` on any `Context`, such as an `Activity`.

Comment: Ahh, will contentresolver be backward and forward compatible?

Comment: @kabuto178: Backward and forward compatible with what?

Comment: That is pre kitkat and for kitkat

Comment: @kabuto178: Those methods have worked since API Level 1. They should work indefinitely for all stream-based `Uri` values (as opposed to ones representing database-style entries, for which you use stuff like `query()` and `update()`).

Comment: Understood and thanks for clearing that up, will do some experimenting.

Comment: So there's no way to get the file path? I don't need the type or the image. I need just the actual path to the file. This has worked for years until very recent versions of Android.

Comment: @Paul: "This has worked for years until very recent versions of Android" -- not really. It worked for select scenarios. Those scenarios are vanishing. You need to treat a `content:` `Uri` like an `http:` `Uri`, and stream in the content. You would not say "I just need the actual path to the file on the Web server that is located half a planet away", because you know that you do not have access to that file. You don't have access to all files from `ContentProviders`, either. Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`, `getType()`, and kin.

Comment: In my case I am opening an intent to select a photo. I only want photos on the device. And all I want back is that photo path. It will always be on the device and it will always have a local path. I'm just not getting that path anymore.

Comment: @Paul: "It will always be on the device and it will always have a local path" -- but **your app may not have access to that path**. For example, `MediaStore` can have indexed contents of removable media, and as of Android 4.4, your **only** access to those files (sans root) is via `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`. You are welcome to build your own UI and your own media index, for whatever files you can reach, if you do not want to use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I had wanted my Intent to only show files local on the device and nothing indexed from Picasa etc. I've built in support for the ContentResolver instead. And I save the stream to a local path that I can access later.

Answer (score -1):

Try this may hepls you

Check Android SDK version when you go for pick image from gallery.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <19){
    Intent intent = new Intent(); 
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getResources().getString(R.string.select_picture)),GALLERY_INTENT_CALLED);
} else {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_KITKAT_INTENT_CALLED);
}
```

Comment: In my case your method `getAbsolutePath` return `null` value

Comment: This will not handle the `Uri` that the question is concerned about. It will not handle lots of `Uri` values, particularly on Android 4.4+.