# Why file.exists() return false?

Tags: android, uri

I have Uri image which I store from ActivityOnResult. I would like to remove this image few steps later.

```
File file=new File(uri.toString());
//I tried file.mkdir() too, but without change
if(file.exists())
     file.delete();
```

But file.exists() return false.
I have no idea what can be the reason. I will be gratefull for any tipis

Comment: There is no way to answer your question as is. The only answer we could give is that the File simply *does not exist*. What is the URI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a content:// URI meaning you can't treat it as a normal file. Instead try this. `getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);`

Comment: Works! And it's simple too ;) Thank you

Comment: But I have one question, I am new in it:) Is any possibility that image Uri from ActivityForResult won't be in content://.. and this solution won't work?

Comment: Well that depends on the Intent you are using in `startActivityForResult`.

Comment: It's  Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)

Comment: Then yes. Because you always request for a content uri.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
File file=new File(uri.getPath());
//I tried file.mkdir() too, but without change
if(file.exists())
     file.delete();
```

Comment: Can you log what `uri.getPath()` is returning? Where the image is located and do you have permission to write? You can check that with `file.canRead()`

Comment: Yes, I have permission in manifest. Image  is located content://media/external/images/media/84 and getPAth() return /external/images/media/84

Comment: That is not a file path. That's a content provider URI. `/external/images/media/84` is not a file and therefore, does not exist.

Comment: Check that solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what is the value in uri?
toString should work, getPath will return the decoded path which might not be valid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check exists on getAbsoluteFile().

Try this

```
 File file=new File(uri.toString());
//I tried file.mkdir() too, but without change
 if(file.getAbsoluteFile().exists()) {
   file.delete();
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, the same

Answer (score 0):

The uri whihc you are getting in onActivityResult might be content scheme uri..Please print the uri.Toi convert content scheme uri to file uri refer the following SO question:

[Get filename and path from URI from mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore)