# How to save video taken from VideoView to external SD card?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-file, android-videoview

I'm trying to save a video, I already successfully captured and put into my `VideoView`, to my SD card. Lots of research, but I found nothing simple and straightforward to help my problem.

I was able to save a photo to the SD card, using very similar code (except not a `Uri` parameter, but a `Bitmap` instead), so I thought the code should be similar, but there is one part (I think?) missing, where the image would normally compress the image in its parameters, videos do not compress, so there is a line in my code `uriVideo.setOutputFile(video.getPath());` that is wrong (red errors). But this is where something needs to happen to make the video suitable for saving. Although this is only a guess. That is where the photo line was that compressed.

Then after my `saveVideo()` method is finished, I call this method on my `VideoView` in another place in my code.

What am I missing? Thanks...

```
 // save your video to SD card
    private void saveVideo(final Uri uriVideo){
        // click the video to save it
        mVideoView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean success = false;

                String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                        (Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES).toString();
                File myDir = new File(root + "/Saved iCute Videos");
                myDir.mkdirs();
                Random generator = new Random();
                int n = 10000;
                n = generator.nextInt(n);
                String videoName = "Video-"+ n +".mp4";
                File file = new File (myDir, videoName);
                if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    uriVideo.setOutputFile(video.getPath()); // WRONG
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    success = true;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (success) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video saved!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error during video saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to get Video from VideoView?

Comment: Yeah, it shows in `VideoView`, but then it's not saved anywhere, so when I kill the app it disappears.

Comment: playing video in VideoView from local storage or using network?

Comment: It was from the camera. Some code where it just captures the video, using the Android camera and plays back immediately once I go back to my activity. But then from there, I am trying to save it by clicking on it.

Comment: The only thing I could find in the docs was "Saving Media Files", but it's incomplete. Here they create a directory and a file name, but I don't get how to actually save it. Plus, is that all a video is a `Uri`? Don't I need to set the type (mp4) or something else? Just not sure. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#saving-media

Comment: but when capturing video if i'm right you are creating uri using real path right? then use that path for getting video instead of `video.getPath()`

Comment: NoniA. : and probably [Get filename and path from uri from mediastore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore) post help in solving issue

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how to adapt that link though.. I don't have a `String` array to iterate through... I'm not even sure why I need to `getPath()`, it was just some code I found. :( I know for sure I can't use `setOutputFile()` because this is a method that belongs to `MediaRecorder`, not `Uri`. Yet I look into `Uri` and don't find any suitable methods. I just wish I understood the steps. I know making a directory, then a file name are two steps, but then should I set my `Uri` parameter input to the file somehow before I put it in the `FileOutputStream`? I'm lost.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out there were multiple problems with this. The first was that you can't use an `OnClickListener` with a `VideoView`, it must be an `OnTouchListener`. Then, I had to get an absolute path instead of just a simple `getPath()`. Then one more line, I had to call [createNewFile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile()) on my File object after I created its directory and name. Didn't even need any other file I/O code.

Here is the final working method:

```
 // save your video to SD card
    protected void saveVideo(final Uri uriVideo){

        // click the video to save it
        mVideoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                boolean success = false;

                // make the directory
                File vidDir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                        (Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES) + File.separator + "Saved iCute Videos");
                vidDir.mkdirs();
                // create unique identifier
                Random generator = new Random();
                int n = 100;
                n = generator.nextInt(n);
                // create file name
                String videoName = "Video_" + n + ".mp4";
                File fileVideo = new File(vidDir.getAbsolutePath(), videoName);

                try {
                    fileVideo.createNewFile();
                    success = true;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (success) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video saved!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error during video saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What device API do you have? It could be a directory issue. I found that to be true on different devices. For instance, some devices might not have a directory named "Movies". But if you were able to create a file, then and only then can `success = true`. So if you are getting to the success toast, then your file might be somewhere in your SD card that you are unaware of.

Comment: You have never used `uriVideo` in here.

Comment: Hi @PriyankaSingh, looks like your question has been answered. Good luck.

Comment: @enadun apologies, the code must have been truncated. Now it's so long ago, I don't have the code anymore. :(