# How to get any File Path ,Name ,Extension from onActivityResult?

Tags: android, onactivityresult

My Codes are:

1.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"myFolder");

            Log.d("path", file.toString());

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "*/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

2.

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, 
    int resultCode, Intent FileReturnedIntent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, FileReturnedIntent);
```

How to get the file path,name,extension? (suppose files are in doc,pdf,csv format)

Comment: have you got any answer

Answer (score 7):

It return the file extention like pdf, doc .. etc

```
 public static String getMimeType(Context context, Uri uri) {
    String extension;

    if (uri.getScheme().equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)) {
         final MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        extension = mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(context.getContentResolver().getType(uri));
    } else {
        extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(new File(uri.getPath())).toString());

    }

    return extension;
}
```

It returns you the real path where you get the file name. One friend use this way and it is really useful.

[Get filename and path from URI from mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore)

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
  Cursor cursor = null;
  try { 
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
  } finally {
    if (cursor != null) {
      cursor.close();
    }
  }
}
```

You get file name from this

```
public String getFileName(Uri uri) {
  String result = null;
  if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    try {
      if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
      }
    } finally {
      cursor.close();
    }
  }
  if (result == null) {
    result = uri.getPath();
    int cut = result.lastIndexOf('/');
    if (cut != -1) {
      result = result.substring(cut + 1);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I am late but it can help others here is the solution.

```
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
                String mime = cr.getType(uri);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this

```
@Override
     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) 
            {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
           }
}
```

Comment: No i don't want image i want other file like pdf,doc what will be in place of  "MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA"  if i want pdf or doc file please help.

Answer (score 0):

Once try as follows if the **FileReturnedIntent** contains File as extras

```
Bundle data1=FileReturnedIntent.getExtras();
File f=(File)data1.get(key);
String path=f.getAbsolutePath();
System.out.println("The file path along with extension is : "+path);
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: FileReturnedIntent.getExtras() is null

Answer (score 0):

Nova day in Kotlin:

```
val myFile = File(data?.data!!.path)
```

Answer (score -5):

you can put String Extra to intent using

```
intent.putExtra("path", your_path);
```

and get it in onActivityResult by

```
FileReturnedIntent.getStringExtra("path");
```

Comment: How is he going to insert the path into the Intent if he is receiving the intent from the ACTION_GET_CONTENT request?

Comment: this answer does not help