# How to use setImageDrawable() with image paths. ANDROID

Tags: android

I am trying to put an image in an imageView by code. I have some images in the Drawable directory but, with other images, I have to use the internal storage. In first case,

```
holder.picture.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_image));
```

works but, in the second case, Android give me this error:

```
BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException:  /storage/emulated/0/Sensia_Sniffer/18_04_2018/18_56_18_photo.JPEG (No such file or directory)
```

and I don't know why. I am using this lines:

```
Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromPath(my_image_path);
holder.picture.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

and in AndroidManifest.xml I have this permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Could you help me with this?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/Sensia_Sniffer/18_04_2018/18_56_18_photo.JPEG` is an external storage path not internal storage.

Comment: Share your code of creating file path.

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Yes sorry, this is external storage but, this is the path that I want to load. The path is correct

Comment: Use an image-loading library, such as Glide or Picasso, so the actual image-loading logic can be performed on a background thread.

Comment: am trying to use a File to put it in a imageView. I have a problem with it because, the path is correct, but the file created doesn't exist. This is my declaration code:

File file = new File(mPlacePictures[position % mPlacePictures.length]);
if (file.exists())
    holder.picture.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(file));
else System.out.println("Error. No such file.");
Path that I want to load:

/storage/emulated/0/Sensia_Sniffer/19_04_2018/09_55_10_photo.JPEG
This image checks the path is correct:

Image path

Which could be the problem?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29163806/9025311

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to ask for runtime permissions for the requested permissions in manifest file.

Needed for Android 6+.