# Converting a File:///... string to an Absolute URI

Tags: java, android, uri, filepath, absolute-path

So I am making an app that lets users pick images from their gallery to display, as well as take photos from the camera.

The image is previewed via a bitmap that takes the string of the file path. When the user takes a photo the code below handles it (and works):

```
String path = mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg"
File pictureFile = new File(path);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
            image1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

The path is of the format like this:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/App/IMG_20150512_130719.jpg
```

However when I try to select from my library, my code is setup so that the string I am returning formatted like this:

```
file:////storage/emulated/0/Pictures/App/IMG_20150512_130719.jpg
```

Now obviously I can (and currently am) split the string and get the path to match the above, but I am curious if there is a standard way to convert between these to?

I saw Uri.parse() but that doesn't work because that returns a URI and I want a String that I can make a file from and then get the absolute path.

If you have a clean suggestion on how I can move from the file://// string to the / string I'm all ears.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore) will give you a hint on how it is done on Android.

Comment: Thanks, the exact solution I used was this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7265235/3324388

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting from file uri to file path:

```
    String fileUri = "file:///storage/emulated/0/";
    String filePath = Uri.parse(fileUri).getPath();
```

Converting from file path to file uri:

```
    String filePath2 = "/storage/emulated/0/";
    String fileUri2 = Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath2)).toString();
```