# cant get file path from URI

Tags: android, android-intent, android-file

I am trying to open a intent that lets me choose a file. Im able to select a file but when I try creating a file with the Uri I got in the OnActivityResult method I get a file size of 0. I dont think Im getting the right file path.

```
  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/TESTAPP4");
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        Uri data = Uri.fromFile(file);
        String type = "*/*";
        intent.setDataAndType(data, type);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 12);
```

onActivityResult:

```
         Uri u= data.getData();
         File file = new File( u.getpath);
         file.length() // give 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
  Cursor cursor = null;
  try { 
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
  } finally {
    if (cursor != null) {
      cursor.close();
    }
  }
}
```

[Get filename and path from URI from mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore)

Comment: @StephenG- im not trying to open up pictures