# Default query with extended ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I extend the ContentProvider to access SQLiteDatabase in my code, but I want to get real path from a content uri. So I use the method provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3414749/4214120)

However since I extend the ContentProvider, when I call `getContentResolver().query()` I actually called the `query()` in the ContentProvider I extended. Where I use `db.query()` there to get data from SQLiteDatabase.

How can I implement the query function in ContentProvider to make it query Uri:`MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA`.
I tried to use `super.query()` , but `query()` is an abstract class.

Comment: `getContentResolver().query()` is `ContentResolver#query`, not `ContentProvider#query`

Comment: @pskink I think `ContentResolver#query` actually calls `ContentProvider#query` it calls `IContentProvider#query` where IContentProvider, is "The ipc interface to talk to a content provider"?

Comment: ok, of course it calls `ContentProvider#query` at the and but it is not the `ContentProvider` you are extending but system's `ContentProvider` associated with `MediaStore.Video.Media#getContentUri(String volumeName)`

Comment: @pskink you're right, thanks