# Android Content Observer - detail about file changed

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, contentobserver

I am using Content Observer on MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI , In this i get notified whenever image file is renamed, but I also want to know the file path of this modified file.

Any way I can do that.

Extras:-
I am having my own Sqlite database where the Media file path is stored together with other information. So I update my database when changes are notified.

So I want to know which file path is renamed and then only change info of that file in my database.

Thanks

Comment: Did you get the solution for the same

Answer (score 0):

Try to query `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA` through cursor loader, so every change will re-trigger onLoadFinished().

Also check [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore).