# Android Gallery not refreshed after Image is saved

Tags: java, android

I am trying to save an image, and alert the Gallery about the new image. The image is not immediately shown in the gallery, but it can take even a few hour to refresh. I use the following code:

```
    String title = "title";
    String r = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), State.pictureWithDekor, title, title);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(r);
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
            new String[] { uri.getPath() }, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.i("TAG", "Finished scanning " + path);
                }
            });
```

the value of `r` after the `insertImage` is `content://media/external/images/media/2082`, the `uri` in the onScanCompleted is `null`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the path returned from the `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage` is not a phisical path. to get the real path, use:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Source: [Get filename and path from URI from mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore)