# How to get real path of selected video from device

Tags: android, path, uri

I want to retrieve real path of video from URI

I open video gallery with **`startActivityForResult`**

```
startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(
                                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
                                .setType("video/*"), "Choose Video"),
                        REQUEST_VIDEO
                        );
```

and I am receiving it in **`onActivityResult`**

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO){

                Uri uri = data.getData();
                String realpath = getRealPathFromURI(getContext(),uri);

            }
}
```

In **`getRealPathFromUri`** is like this;

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

But realpath always return null;

I search for that but still returns null

It currents with sdk_version?

or is it changed for `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA` to `MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA`?

I am stuck here, having no clue, kindly suggest! Any help will be very valuable

--Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? Can you please update this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
public static String getRealVideoPathFromURI(ContentResolver contentResolver,
                                                 Uri contentURI) {
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(contentURI, null, null, null,
                null);
        if (cursor == null)
            return contentURI.getPath();
        else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Video.VideoColumns.DATA);
            try {
                return cursor.getString(idx);
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but still return null;

Comment: In onActivityResult change this,                                                                  String video= getRealVideoPathFromURI(getContentResolver(), videoUri);

Comment: String path = getRealVideoPathFromURI(getActivity().getContentResolver(),videouri);

yes i tried it but still null

Answer (score 1):

As far as I could understand, the way you get "real" file path depends on the Android's SDK version.

Scenario 1) I was running **targetSdkVersion 28** on Emulator and I can get the "real" file path with this simple command in `onActivityResult`:

```
data.getData().getPath();
```

Scenario 2) But in my physical device **SDK level 25**, I get exactly what you showed: a content path or something like this.

```
content://media/external/file/3131
```

Where the "real" file path was:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Download/lista_produtos.xlsx
```

In order to get the "real" file path in my physical device and also take into account my emulator, I used this piece of code inside the `onActivityResult`:

```
    Uri uri = data.getData();
    String realPath;
    if (DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(getApplicationContext(), uri)) {

        String[] path = uri.getPath().split(":");
        realPath = path[1];
        Log.i("debinf ProdAct", "Real file path on Emulator: "+realPath);
    } else {

        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getApplicationContext(), uri, null, null, null,null);
        Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        realPath = cursor.getString(idx);
        Log.i("debinf ProdAct", "Real file path in physical device "+realPath);
        cursor.close();
    }
```

I guess in your case, the more appropiated index is:

```
int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
```

I hope it helps, because I have not used your code. And as I said before, it depends on the Android's SDK version.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49687681/4300670

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the `Uri` , you can obtain the absolute file path this way:

```
File myFile = new File(uri.getPath());
myFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: I tried but i have question,
It returns /document/video:####(####is number)

I think it is not realpath from video file,
because when i enter file manager and see selected video files info,
it returns /storage/0/emulated/...
like this
I want that path

Comment: inside the `onActivityResult()` what do you obtain when you log : `data.getData().toString()` ? let me know

Comment: Uri uri = data.getData();
                String path = uri.getPath().toString();

log said, /document/video:2745

Comment: if i may ask what's the requirement by obtaining the absolute path?

Comment: I want selected videofile id from path

Comment: is it to play or upload that video? whats the end goal?

Comment: sorry for late comment, i upload that video

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have not granted reading and writing to external storage permission. I have the same problem and granting the permission didn't solve it. Who knows, may it solves yours!