# File not found... selecting a video from gallery

Tags: android

I have both 
    /document/video:5312
and 
    content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A5312

as "URI" or "absolute paths" to a video file that I selected from gallery and I feed it into new File();

```
File selectedFile = new File(selectedFilePath);
```

I've tried both of the upper URI/Paths and they just don't work.
Does *NOT* work. The file is *NOT* found.

What format does File() require?
This path is valid. How do I open it with File()?

Comment: your question is so vague

Comment: edited it a bit.. better?

Comment: i actually didnt get what you want ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore  may help or be relevant. see approved ans there

Answer (score 2):

> "URI" or "absolute paths" to a video file that I selected from gallery

Those are `Uri` values. They are not filesystem paths, nor can you get filesystem paths for them.

> The file is NOT found.

That is because they are not files. `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A5312` has a scheme of `content`, not `file`.

Similarly, `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41900707/file-not-found-selecting-a-video-from-gallery` is not a file, as that `Uri` has a scheme of `https`.

> How do I open it with File()?

You don't, any more than you open `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41900707/file-not-found-selecting-a-video-from-gallery` using `File`.

Instead, [you use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html), just as you might use OkHttp or `HttpUrlConnection` to get an `InputStream` on an `https` `Uri`.

Comment: Can you help me with an example of uploading a file with this method...? I only found one for Xamarin on google.

Comment: @DavidKachlon: Well, few HTTP client APIs work purely off of an `InputStream`, in case they need to restart the HTTP operation. You would have to see if your chosen HTTP API supports `InputStream` (e.g., OkHttp does not). If it does, great. If not, also open a `FileOutputStream` somewhere (e.g., `getCacheDir()`), and copy the bytes from the `InputStream` to the `FileOutputStream`. Then, you can use your copy of the content as a file, deleting it when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Thank you.

Here's what I managed....

```
    String[] perms = {"android.permission. WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"};

    int permsRequestCode = 200;

   requestPermissions(perms, permsRequestCode);



  public void convertFile(Uri urx)
        throws IOException {

    ContentResolver test = getContentResolver();
    InputStream initialStream =  test.openInputStream(urx);


    byte[] buffer = new byte[initialStream.available()];
    initialStream.read(buffer);

    File xpath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);


    File targetFile = new File(xpath, "/test.mp4");
    OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
    outStream.write(buffer);
    uploadFile(targetFile.getPath());

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int permsRequestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults){

    switch(permsRequestCode){

        case 200:

            boolean writeAccepted = grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

            break;

    }

}
```

I get an EACES error upon trying to write my .mp4 file. Is there a way to "write it to memory" ? Or maybe you can resolve this issue.