# Android - save video with content provider

Tags: android, video, android-contentprovider

I try to save an video to sd card. To test my codes, I save the selected video from gallery to another folder.

I call gallery intent, and pick a video. onActivityResult function code is below :

```
if(requestCode == VIDEO_PICK) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                String path = getRealPathFromURI(data.getData());
                Log.i("@@Path ", " " + path);

                File file = new File(new URI(path));
                Uri uri = addVideo(file);
            } catch(Exception err) {
                Log.i("@@Exception", " " + err);
            }
        }
}

public Uri addVideo(File videoFile) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, "My video title");
    values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "player");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, videoFile.getAbsolutePath());

    return getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

}
```

addVideo function throws an exception.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute:

How can I get absolute path from uri? I tried uri.toString() and uri.getPath(). They didn't work.

getRealPathFromUri implementation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore?rq=1)

Comment: all you need is `Uri`, that is `data.getData()`

Comment: "How can I get absolute path from uri?" -- you don't. There is no requirement for a `Uri` to point to a file.

Comment: @pskink I don't understand. Should I create a file from uri?

Comment: see @CommonsWare's comment

Answer (score 0):

> Should I create a file from uri?

If the `Uri` scheme is `file`, then `getPath()` will be a filesystem path pointing to the file, and presumably you can read it.

If the `Uri` scheme is `content`, then `getPath()` is a meaningless string. Ideally, you just use the `Uri` itself, or you use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`. If, for some reason, you absolutely need a file, use that `InputStream` to copy the bytes of the content to some file that you control.