# Android: How to get an image from gallery if image size less than 1MB?

Tags: android

Android: How to get an image from gallery if image size less than 1MB ??

+++My Code:

```
Bitmap bitmap;

private void onBrowse() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 111);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == 111 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
            Uri path = data.getData();
            File file = new File(path.getPath());
            long size = file.length();
            Log.i("size=", size + "");
            if(size > 1048576){ // 1MB
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image must less than 1MB.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), path);
                ivImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

+++Output: I/size=: 0
I selected image 3.2MB, why did output 0?
I want to show an image in ivImage if file size of selected image less than 1MB.
Please help!!!

Comment: so the log prints size 0? If so then the path/file is not valid, does not exist

Comment: As per the docs here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length--, if it returns `0L` the file does not exist. Check the path you are getting.

Comment: yes, but output should 3355443 why 0?

Comment: Because your `path`URI is not pointing to an actual file. What value do you get in it?

Comment: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A62720

Comment: You need to convert the content uri to an actual path. Refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10564727/4350275

Comment: it always return null