# How to know the _ID of the Images added with MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage()

Tags: android, mediastore

Is there a way to know the `_ID` of the image I add to `MediaStore` using `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage()`??

`MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage()` returns the `Uri` of the image added.

I need to know the `_ID`, in order to query `MediaStore` and get all the image data, right after the image was saved in `MediaStore`.

Is there another way, even without the `_ID`, to query `MediaStore` and get all the data of the last image I added?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could get information from the MediaStore like this from the URI:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
  Cursor cursor = null;
  try { 
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
  } finally {
    if (cursor != null) {
      cursor.close();
    }
  }
}
```

More info here: [Get filename and path from URI from mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore)

And here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html

Comment: not working when I'm uninstall and install again in android 12