# Getting the full file path for a specific file in Android

Tags: android, filepath

Is this even possible?
Or the file picker intent can only return Uris?

Comment: any code of what have you tried ?

Comment: Is this helpful to you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore