# Can't play video in videoview from listview

Tags: android, listview, android-videoview

I can't manage to play a video on videoview from a listview on the same layout.
When clicking on listview item it displays a message "Can't play this video".
I have taken the READ_EXTERNAL_PERMISSION in Manifest.
All my videos in my phone are displayed on listview but the video won't play.

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(A1.this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(A1.this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(A1.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(A1.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
        }
    } else {
        doStuff();
    }
}

public void doStuff(){
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    getVideo();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String  myUrl = adapter.getItem(position);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(myUrl);
            videoView1.setVideoURI(uri);
            videoView1.start();

        }
    });
}
public void getVideo(){
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri videoUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor videoCursor = contentResolver.query(videoUri,null,null,null,null);

    if(videoCursor != null && videoCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int songTitle = videoCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE);
        int songAlbum = videoCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.ALBUM);

        do{
            String currentTitle = videoCursor.getString(songTitle);
            String currentAlbum = videoCursor.getString(songAlbum);
            arrayList.add(currentTitle + "\n" + currentAlbum);
        }while(videoCursor.moveToNext());
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST: {
            if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(A1.this,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(A1.this, "Permission Granted" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    doStuff();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(A1.this, "No Permission granted" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    finish();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: in your adapter, you don't have valid uri **arrayList.add(currentTitle + "\n" + currentAlbum);** this is not the valid url.

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore

Comment: @KrishnaSharma I changed **`arrayList.add(currentTitle + "\n" + currentAlbum);`** to **`arrayList.add(currentTitle);`** and it works fine, the video mow plays perfectly. Thank You

Comment: Great !! glad to know that worked. Lets close this question then. Posting as an answer you may accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the my code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.layout_a1);
            listView1 = findViewById(R.id.lv1);
            videoView1 = findViewById(R.id.vv1);
            mediaController = new MediaController(A1.this);

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(A1.this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(A1.this,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(A1.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(A1.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
                }
            } else {
                doStuff();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST: {
                    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(A1.this,
                                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            Toast.makeText(A1.this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            doStuff();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(A1.this, "No Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void doStuff() {
            arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
            Uri videoUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            final Cursor videoCursor = contentResolver.query(videoUri, null, null, null, null);

            if (videoCursor != null && videoCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int songTitle = videoCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE);

                do {
                    String currentTitle = videoCursor.getString(songTitle);
                    arrayList.add(currentTitle);
                } while (videoCursor.moveToNext());
            }
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
            listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

            listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    System.gc();
                    video_column_index = videoCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
                    videoCursor.moveToPosition(position);
                    String filename = videoCursor.getString(video_column_index);
                    videoView1.setVideoPath(filename);
                    videoView1.setMediaController(new MediaController(A1.this));
                    videoView1.requestFocus();
                    videoView1.start();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```