# not getting how to use incoming image from android chooser intent

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to display the image in main page. the image will come from whats app profile upon sharing that image to my app.

app.js

```
if (intent.getClipData()) {
        let imageUri = intent.getClipData().getItemAt(0).getUri()
        console.log(imageUri);
    //  content://com.whatsapp.fileprovider/external/WhatsApp/.Shared/photo.jpg
        global.imageUri = imageUri;
    }
```

xml

```
<StackLayout class="p-20">
       <Image src="{{ imageUri }}" stretch="none" />

    </StackLayout>
```

viewModel

```
imageUri: global.imageUri,
```

getting this error

```
Error in downloadBitmap - java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: content
```

i need to know how to use incoming images from intent services of android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add these things in android manifest

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
```

to handle it copy paste this code anywhere you like

```
if (platform_1.isAndroid) {
        application.android.on(application.AndroidApplication.activityCreatedEvent, function (args) {
            var activity = args.activity;
            // Get intent, action and MIME type
            var intent = activity.getIntent();
            var action = intent.getAction();
            var type = intent.getType();
            if (android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND === action && type != null) {
                if (type.startsWith("text/")) {
                    handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
                }
                else if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
                    handleSendImage(intent); // Handle single image being sent
                }
            }
            else if (android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE === action && type != null) {
                if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
                    handleSendMultipleImages(intent); // Handle multiple images being sent
                }
            }
            else {
                // Handle other intents, such as being started from the home screen
            }
        });
    }
```

```
function handleSendText(intent) {
    if (platform_1.isAndroid) {
        var sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        if (sharedText != null) {
            // Update UI to reflect text being shared
            console.log("sharedText: ", sharedText);
            console.log("Text received!");
            vm.set("sharedText", sharedText);
        }
    }
}
function handleSendImage(intent) {
    if (platform_1.isAndroid) {
        var imageUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        if (imageUri != null) {
            // Update UI to reflect image being shared
            console.log("Image received!");
            var appContext = application.android.context;
            var bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(appContext.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
            console.log("bitmap: ", bitmap);
            vm.set("bitmap", bitmap);
        }
    }
}
function handleSendMultipleImages(intent) {
    if (platform_1.isAndroid) {
        var imageUris = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        if (imageUris != null) {
            // Update UI to reflect multiple images being shared
            console.log("imageUris: ", imageUris);
            console.log("Multiple images received!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly display image using content uri. You will have to parse the actual file url using [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media#EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)

You may refer the source code of [nativescript-imagepicker](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-imagepicker/blob/master/src/imagepicker.android.ts#L47) for working sample. It returns the actual file path after parsing the content uri when you a image is selected from gallery.

Comment: I'm new to nativescript and not aware of android code. if you dont mind kindly explain me how to use this code 'contentUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;'  in nativescipt app.

Comment: i found this answer is very simple can you tell me how to use it in nativescript. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7265235/11404646

Comment: Did you even check the plug-in link above, it uses the same code which you could copy / paste at least.

Comment: i'm reffering imagepicker plugin itself but if i copy paste it directly it is giving error. so please tell me which part i need to copy. for a newbie it looks really tougher, it took a day to observe how image picker works but still i'm not able to get what you said.  hope you understand.

Comment: Just copy the whole `_calculateFileUri` method, pass your uri from intent to the method and that should return you the exact file path.