# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null error in Java code

Tags: java, android, kotlin, illegalargumentexception, non-nullable

I am using [this Kfilter library](https://github.com/isaac-udy/Kfilter) for adding filters in my code written in JAVA.

I am getting this error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull` while adding the image to the Imageview.

This is my code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            if (data == null) {
                showMessage("Failed to open picture!");
                return;
            }
            else
                {
                resultUri = data.getData();

                kfilter.setContentPath(resultUri.toString()); //Error occurs here
                kfilter.setFilters(filter);


            }

        }

    }
```

This is the error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/0/1/content://media/external/images/media/120425/ORIGINAL/NONE/916748167 flg=0x1 clip={text/uri-list U:content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/0/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F120425/ORIGINAL/NONE/916748167} }} to activity {com.unit.helloworld/com.unit.helloworld.CompetitionPackage.AddNewPhotoAcivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter $this$startsWith
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4596)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4638)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1976)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6912)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:860)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter $this$startsWith
        at kotlin.text.StringsKt__StringsJVMKt.startsWith(Unknown Source:2)
        at kotlin.text.StringsKt__StringsJVMKt.startsWith$default(StringsJVM.kt:332)
        at com.isaacudy.kfilter.KfilterMediaFile.<init>(KfilterMediaFile.kt:32)
        at com.isaacudy.kfilter.KfilterView.setContentPath(KfilterView.kt:98)
        at com.unit.helloworld.CompetitionPackage.AddNewPhotoAcivity.onActivityResult(AddNewPhotoAcivity.java:208)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7468)
```

All I can find is to add `?` to the code. But I have written in Java and the library is developed in kotlin.
How to solve this?

Comment: Have you checked `data.getData()` is returning the `Uri`. Secondly, On which OS you are running?

Comment: @MustansarSaeed Yes I toasted the Uri. Its showing the proper location. I am currently using this on oreo.

Answer (score 0):

After closer inspection of the stack trace you'll notice that the error arises in `KfilterMediaFile`. The following is the relevant section:

```
val extension = path.split(".").last()
val mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension)

when {
    mimeType.startsWith("video") -> processAsVideo() // the error arises here
    mimeType.startsWith("image") -> processAsImage()
    else -> error = MediaError.ERROR_INVALID_FILE_TYPE
}
```

The `mimeType` is null if the `MimeTypeMap` could not map the file extension to a mime type. Therefore I'd recommend that you check that the type of your file is correct. If it is you could ask the library maintainer about the problem, such that this case is handled more gracefully.

Comment: Is there a way to resolve this in the code itself? Because the library has been dead past year

Comment: One workaround would probably be to do the same things the library does and call the lib function only if your checks succeeded. But that's not really the most elegant solution. Alternatively you could fork the library and just fix it yourself. I don't really know of any other good approached to the problem.

Comment: I tried using this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10564727/11428585 . Is this the correct way? Because now its not throwing errors

Comment: But the image is not visible in the view! :(

Comment: The answer by Jitendra ramoliya looks somewhat similar to the getUriPath function in the library example. But i can't help you with that because I've never used the library. You could try to translate the example code to Java, test if it works and then integrate it in your app

Comment: Ok i will try it!