# Android Studio Mediastore.Audio.Media.DATA is Deprecated, any alternatives?

Tags: android, kotlin

i am trying to access mp3 files on external storage, and iam using mediastore to retrieve it. However android studio seems to point that obtaining it trough mediastore.audio.media.DATA is deprecated. Heres my code

```
        val mediaUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        val select = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!=0"

        val rs = contentResolver.query(mediaUri, null, select, null, null)


        if (rs != null) {
            while (rs.moveToNext()) {
                val uri = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA))
                val author = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST))
                val title = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE))
                val albumId = rs.getLong(rs.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ID))

                val uriImage = Uri.Builder()
                uriImage
                    .scheme("content")
                    .authority("media")
                    .appendPath("external")
                    .appendPath("audio")
                    .appendPath("albumart")
                    .appendPath(albumId.toString())


                val music = Music(title, author, uri, uriImage.build())
                listMusic.add(music)


            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue myself, and it's weird how hard it was to find out what to use instead. If something is deprecated, they should at least include a link on what to do instead. The Spring framework is pretty good at that, so maybe I've been spoiled.

Use `MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns._ID` then you can build a content URI like:

```
val mediaId = rs.getString(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns._ID)
val uri = Uri.parse(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString() + File.separator + mediaId)
```

I was using it with the `MediaPlayer`, so I used that URI like:

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, uri)
```

Hopefully this helps someone else who wanted to stay current and found your question.

[Source](https://github.com/android/uamp/issues/325)

Also to expand on removing the use of `Mediastore.Audio.Media.DATA`, I found I could still search like I was using `MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA`, via searching on `MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DISPLAY_NAME`. Although I preferred also including the relative path.

Example:

```
val c: Cursor? = context.contentResolver.query(
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    null,
    "${MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.RELATIVE_PATH} like ? AND ${MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DISPLAY_NAME}=?",
    arrayOf("Audiobooks/%", "some audio book.mp3"),
    null
)
```

So previously I was search in `/storage/emulated/0/AudioBook/%`, but now using relative paths it's `AudioBook/%` combined with the `DISPLAY_NAME`. So it's not as convenient as using one field, but instead two.

Comment: Thanks i'll try it out, the official documentation on how to use this things is quite confusing.